# Tridion Sites10 presentation server error

Tags: dd4t, java, upgrade, sites-10

We use Tridion Sites9 with DD4T java and are going to upgrade to Sites10.
We move Sites9's web application modules to the sites10 presentation server and replace sites9's jar files with sites10's jar files from installation media in the following folders

Content Delivery\roles\api\rest\java\lib
Content Delivery\roles\content\standalone\lib\

We found the following error.

> 13-Nov-2023 02:21:54.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
> 13-Nov-2023 02:21:54.204 ERROR [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart class [com.sdl.delivery.content.preview.session.SessionPreviewServletContextListener] Error configuring application listener of class
> javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance.
> at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:98)
> at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:342)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:864)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
> at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:437)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:163)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4420)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4939)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1184)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1932)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1094)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
> 13-Nov-2023 02:21:54.220 重大 [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart class [com.sdl.delivery.content.preview.session.SessionPreviewRequestContextListener] Error configuring application listener of class
> javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance.

1. using jar files are correct?
2. How to fix the error?

Could you give me some advice?
Let me know if we can give you any other information.

Comment: are you still using in-process API with your web app?

Comment: also please update your ticket is it dd4t java or dd4t .net?

Comment: @Velmurugan I am using dd4t Java. I don't think I am using the in-process API, how can I be sure I am using the in-process API? BR

Comment: @Velmurugan
Sorry, installation is incorrect, so we'll install Sites 10 again.
I'd appriciate if you tell us DD4T is still available in Sites 10 or not, if you know.
Because we are using DD4T on Sites 9, so we want to keep using DD4T on Sites 10, if it's possible.

Comment: DD4T is an open-source project, you may want to contact the project. I do see an update posted recently adding Sites 10 support: https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Providers.Tridion10.CIL

Comment: @NunoLinhares Thank you for comment, but I use DD4T Java. your link is for .net, right?

Comment: Is this the right project then? https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java - I would reach out to the maintainers of that project and check if they're planning to update it, when, and if you can contribute. :)